# Azure Timer Function throws a 404 on a blob never specified

Tags: azure-functions

I tried to debug on my machine a trigger of an azure function... when I execute it I got

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Service request failed.
Status: 404 (The specified container does not exist.)
ErrorCode: ContainerNotFound
```

on this piece of code, that has not been developed by me

[image]

If I comment the `[TimerTrigger("%TimerSchedule%", RunOnStartup = true)]`  the application starts, but I cannot debug the time trigger...

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code as snippet instead of image.

Comment: Also share your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that the specified container for the blob that the function is trying to access does not exist.

This is due to several reasons.

1. The blob container was never created or deleted accidentally.
2. The connection string to the blob container is incorrect or invalid.
3. The function code is referring to the wrong blob container.

> You need to check the blob container exists and that the connection string to it is correct.
> You can also try specifying the correct blob container name in the code if it was not already done.

And if you are not sure which blob container the function is trying to access, you can try enabling logging for your function and looking at the logs to see which blob container is causing the error.

The issue with debugging the time trigger is you can try deploying the function to Azure and then use the Azure portal to enable the timer trigger and set its schedule.

This will allow you to debug the function when the timer trigger fires. Alternatively, you can try using the Azure Functions Core Tools to debug the function locally.

For more information refer to the
Thanks to `Esther Fan` for the [blob-trigger](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger.md)

Thanks to `Gaurav Mantri`  for the [SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647791/azure-requestfailedexception-service-request-failed-status-404-the-specifie)